# mysql join query not using subselect()

Tags: mysql, join

In my application I get an username.
The design of tables is following:

users table:

id|username

port table:

user_id|port

What's the best way to write a query finding the port(a user can have only one port associated to his id) belonging to the user by using his id? I don't want to write to querys for this.

Comment: Can you post the SQL you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Just join the two tables:

```
select port from users inner join ports
on users.id = port.user_id 
Where users.id = <userid>
```